# text field is not reading values by clicking button but until i add the value physically into text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I have three text fields each field has the button to increment or decrement the value and final text field which is going to show calculate of each of field values.

All are working well but the problem is. Whenever I'm adding a value into the those three input field physically so its getting the value and displaying it.
first pro -> but whenever im trying to add value through of the button clicking its doesn't displaying the values.

second pro-> by default im adding values each of text field they should display final calculated values into my fourth textfield which is right top of all
but until I touch any of text field it is not displaying the calculated values on the same.

Please help me it is really needed. Here is my source code.

```js
window.sum = () => document.getElementById('get_my_value').value =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3')).map(e => parseInt(e.value) || 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

function increaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;
}

function decreaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;
}

function increaseValueSec() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueSec() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = value;
}

function increaseValueThird() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt3').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt3').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueThird() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt3').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt3').value = value;
}
```

```html
<?php 
   $firstvalue = 1;
   $secondvalue = 1;
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label>Night</label>
        <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="get_my_value" onchange="dateRangeSelector()" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subsfirst" class="subsfirst" onclick="decreaseValueFirst()">
  <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum()" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addfirst" class="addfirst" onclick="increaseValueFirst()">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subssec" class="subssec" onclick="decreaseValueSec()">
  <input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum()" style="margin-right:10px;" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addsec" class="addsec" onclick="increaseValueSec()">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="substhird" class="substhird" onclick="decreaseValueThird()">
  <input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="sum()" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addthird" class="addthird" onclick="increaseValueThird()">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you can see there is not work by clicking button but its working until you add values physically.

Second is right top there is final calculated text field which is showing totalvalues it is also not displaying values by default until you add or click on any of each text field.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons don't work as they don't trigger the `onkeyup` method which is used to calculate the `sum` and display the sum by calling the `sum()` method. So, instead, you can call both the increase/decrease functions and the `sum()` method when you click the button (thus adding/subtracting and recalculating and displaying the sum):

`onclick="decreaseValueFirst(); sum();"`

You can apply this for each of your buttons to get the following working result:

```js
window.sum = () =>
  document.getElementById('get_my_value').value =
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3')
  ).map(e => parseInt(e.value) || 0)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

function increaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;
}

function increaseValueSec() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueSec() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt2').value = value;
}

function increaseValueThird() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt3').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('txt3').value = value;

}

function decreaseValueThird() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt3').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt3').value = value;
}
```

```html
<?php 
   $firstvalue = 1;
   $secondvalue = 1;
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label>Night</label>
        <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="get_my_value" onchange="dateRangeSelector()" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subsfirst" class="subsfirst" onclick="decreaseValueFirst(); sum();">
  <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum()" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addfirst" class="addfirst" onclick="increaseValueFirst(); sum();">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="subssec" class="subssec" onclick="decreaseValueSec(); sum();">
  <input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum()" style="margin-right:10px;" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addsec" class="addsec" onclick="increaseValueSec(); sum();">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="substhird" class="substhird" onclick="decreaseValueThird(); sum();">
  <input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="sum()" />
  <input type="button" value="+" id="addthird" class="addthird" onclick="increaseValueThird(); sum();">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @mdserver no worries! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your `sum()` function on the `keyup` event on the text boxes. When you change the value in the text box from the +/- buttons, the `keyup` event doesn't fire. Call your `sum()` function after you change the value.

Sample code:

```
function decreaseValueFirst() {
  // body... 
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('txt1').value = value;
  sum();  // <-- New line added
}
```